# Interpretation of LM statistic and J-Bera statistic

Tags: interpretation, eviews

[image: VEC serial correlation LM test]

[image: VEC residual Normality test]

How should I interpret the results of autocorrelation and normality from the tables enclosed herewith?

Answer (score 0):

When faced with tables like this you mostly need to figure out two things:

a. What is the null hypothesis?

b. What does the "Prob." column tell me about this null hypothesis?

On the first table you have two tests: LRE and Rao F. The top line of the table tells you the null hypothesis is **no serial correlation**. To reject this null hypothesis at 95% confidence, you would need p-values smaller than or equal to $0.05$. Under the "Prob." columns, both tests give you p-values larger than that. So, neither test can reject the hypothesis of no serial correlation. In other words, there is no evidence of serial correlation at lag 1.

For the second table, you can Google what the null hypothesis of a Jarque-Bera test is. It happens to be **normality or, more precisely, that the vector under consideration has skweness and kurtosis similar to a Normal distribution**. You would then look at the p-values under the "Prob." column, and realize that the hypothesis of normality is not rejected for any of the seven Components (whatever they are). From the last line, you can also read the result of a joint test of all of the Components being Normal.